# Playground in Xcode 11.6 not executing the Code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11

I just started into swift programing but unfortunately I ran into issue at the very first day.I installed Xcode 11.6 in my MacBook Air 2019, was Excited to run first Hello Playground code but end up with no output on the right bar of playground..

I have done every single thing found in Stackoverflow either in google.but dint meet the solution yet..

CheckList which I have tried to resolve the issue

1.i have uninstall and reinstall
2.change the build setting into legacy
3.Done checking Editor>run playground
4.File/New/Tab
5.adding import PlaygroundSupport
6.Chaning iOS to macOS

I am adding screen shot link to make u people more understandable regarding my problem.you will notice no output in picture.

[Click here to See the Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqYha.jpg)

Comment: It's quite weird, I just did exactly the same as you and it run fine. I'm also on 11.6 mac os 10.15.6.
On the screenshot thought, it seems you didn't run the script by clicking the little triangle on the beginning of the line 5. You can also run it by clicking the triangle in the bottom window or Editor-> Run Playground (cmd+⇧+↩︎)

Comment: I have already tried it before 
running from Bottom even running from editor too

Comment: What happened precisely? nothing at all or something happened but the code is not executed?

Comment: no nothing at all happened, its not about code its about playground which is not even showing the output and not even the "hello playground" on right.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the Response..
Finally I've solved the issue with my playground after long troubleshooting.
Let me know if anyone will have the same problem.

Comment: We didn’t help much, but If you solved the issue you should write an answer explaining what you did for other people finding this post.

Comment: It was with macOS Catalina version 10.15.5 that does’nt allow to debug playground code in Xcode 11.6

so all I did is to updated macOS to 10.15.6 and after restarting its automatically started installing other components of Xcode 11.6 and ask for administrator permission to start the running of playground.And that end up with running the playground smoothly.